# Position absolute display an image in one place and then moves it in another

Tags: css, cordova

Hi I am having some issues with positioning an image in the center on Android.I am using web technologies javascript, html/css and Cordova for the app.

I have a initial splash screen that will display a loading box and the title of the app.

I position the title absolute and set the left and top to 50%.For some reason when the app is rendered the app title is displayed on the lower rights and after a split second it uses the style I gave it and moves it.Here is my code:

```
    <div class="splashpage" style="height: 100%;">
        <div class="wrap">
            <h1>AppTitle</h1>
            <a id="refresh-link" class="hiddenSection">Er is geen internetverbinding. Activeer de internetverbinding om verder te gaan.</a>
            <div id="refresh-loading" class="hiddenSection" style="font-size: 14px; padding: 20px;">
                <div class="loadingRota"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>



   .splashpage .wrap {
      background: #009ae0;
      height: 100%;
      vertical-align: middle;
      text-align: center;
    }
    .splashpage .wrap h1 {
      color: #ffffff;
      font-size: 60px;
      height: 60px;
      position: absolute;
      top: 50%;
      left: 50%;
      width: 350px;
      margin: -30px 0 0 -150px;
    }
```

I tryed loading this in the browser in Android and it works normaly.But if I run this as the Cordova app it has the issue I mentioned.Also this works normaly on iOS devices.

Another thing I noticed if I try position using pixels it displays the AppTitle in the position I requested without the issue that I mentioned.

Has anyone encountered this problem before?

Comment: Android has nothing to deal with question.

Comment: I'ts an issue that is reproduced only on Android but you are rights it's not a native Android problem I will remove the tag